# fonts not working in subdirectories

Tags: css, import

I am using several different fonts for my website, [sarkelliancreed.comule.com](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com), and the fonts are not loading in a certain page: [sarkelliancreed.comule.com/contact](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/contact). In all other pages as far as I can tell the fonts are working. I am using `@import` to get the stylesheets from different fonts. The main stylesheet, `main.css`, is included with a `<link>`. Why aren't the fonts showing up?

Comment: Please include relevant code **in the question itself**. Links to your website are not helpful for later users, and are a moving target as you try to fix things. This is doubly so seeing your websites are blocked by Trend Micro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CSS standards any @import rules (and @charset rules) must be the first statements in a CSS files. See this link for further info:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import

So, if you move the @import sections to the top of your CSS file, this may solve your problem.

I also recommend validating your code at the following site: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: No, this isn't working...

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit hasty. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the CSS file "header for html.css" which contains all the font related CSS, is not getting included in the contact page header. Try checking the source when the contact page is loaded.
Also, a good suggestion is to not use file names like "header for html.css" and rename it to something like "header_for_html.css".

Comment: Yes, but when I checked my error console, it didn't give me any 404 errors. It usually does that when it can't find a stylesheet. Also, other pages which have exactly the same code run the fonts.

Comment: The issue is not about browser not finding the stylesheet. You only get those 404 error when the CSS file is listed in header and not fetched. Here the CSS file is not at all listed in your markup, so you won't get any 404 errors. Check your markup code where you are adding that "header for html.css" file. I guess it is not included in the contact page's header.